# JAVA using assigned values from an array in a calculation

Tags: java, arrays, selection

This is a very basic question but I have just started out with JAVA and have hit a bit of a bump with regards to arrays.

What I am trying to do is populate an array with 6 pieces of information from the user:

- Number of employees to be input,
- An alphanumeric employee number,
- A first name,
- A last Name,
- the number of hours they have worked,
- a number input corresponding to Pay Scale.

So far I have gotten these inputs into an array in JAVA however what I wanted to do was use corresponding number input to select a constant within the Pay Scale array and then use that constant to calculate the wages of each employee.

for instance employee 1 worked 10 hours at scale 0 so that would be 10*4.50
and employee worked 10 hours at scale 1 which would be 10*4.62

```
import java.util.Arrays; //imports Array utility
import java.util.Scanner; //imports Scanner utility

public class test1 {

    static Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);   //Adds a keyboard input 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Employees: ");
        int employees = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] Employee = new String[employees];
        String[] FirstName = new String[employees];
        String[] LastName = new String[employees];
        double[] HoursWorked = new double[employees];
        double[] PayScale = {4.50,4.62,4.90,5.45,6.20};


        for (int i = 0; i < Employee.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Employee Number: ");
            Employee[i] = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Employee's First name: ");
            FirstName[i] = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Employee's Last name: ");
            LastName[i] = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Employee's Hours worked: ");
            HoursWorked[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter Employee's Payscale (Number 0 to 4): ");
            PayScale[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < HoursWorked.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Employee " + Employee[i] + " " + FirstName[i] + " " + LastName[i] + " has "
                        + HoursWorked[i] * PayScale[0]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I even close to a solution on this?

Is what I'm asking possible in JAVA?

Maybe I'm just looking at this the wrong way, but any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

edit

OK I added the extras array into the code 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Employees: ");
        int employees = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] Employee = new String[employees];
        String[] FirstName = new String[employees];
        String[] LastName = new String[employees];
        double[] HoursWorked = new double[employees];
        int[]PayScale2 = {0,1,2,3,4};
        double[] PayScale = {4.50,4.62,4.90,5.45,6.20};

I'm just unsure as to where I'd index the original PayScale array with the

PayScale[PayScale2[i]]

would it go into the for statement codeblock? (I have tried putting it in there however I get an error that it's not a statement :/

Comment: 1. It's spelled Java, not JAVA. 2. Learn about objects and classes. You shouldn't have N arrays of String or double. You should have a single array of Employee objects. And an Employee would have a number, a first name, a last name, etc.

Comment: *Java* way of doing something like this would be to create `Employee` class and encapsulate all the calculations inside it.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
+ HoursWorked[i] * PayScale[0]);
```

to

```
+ HoursWorked[i] * PayScale[i]);
```

apart from that seems to me like you're doing what you're saying you should be doing..

you already have the `payscales` from here:  `double[] PayScale = {4.50,4.62,4.90,5.45,6.20};` so the following doesn't make a lot of sense:

```
System.out.print("Enter Employee's Payscale (Number 0 to 4): ");
            PayScale[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
```

First of all, if you want to `keep this number (Number 0 to 4) separately`, you should use `another Array`, `not` the one where you keep the `Payscales`, then you could `index` to the `first array` which keeps the `different rates`.. or else you could `directly` use the first array `if you know` the pay scale for every employee.. in the end it has to do with what you want to do and how you want to do it, but the logic and the tools are there. `If you call the 2nd array PayScale2` for example:

```
 System.out.print("Enter Employee's Payscale (Number 0 to 4): ");
            PayScale2[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
```

then you can `index to the first array` for example:

```
PayScale[PayScale2[i]]
```

in which case if the user inputs `0` then `PayScale2[i]` would be `0` then `PayScale[PayScale2[i]]` would be `PayScale[0]` or `4.5` or whatever you set the value equal to at the first array

Comment: sorry I hit that a bit early. I meant to say that I added the extras array into the code         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Employees: ");
        int employees = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] Employee = new String[employees];
        String[] FirstName = new String[employees];
        String[] LastName = new String[employees];
        double[] HoursWorked = new double[employees];
        int[]PayScale2 = {0,1,2,3,4};
        double[] PayScale = {4.50,4.62,4.90,5.45,6.20}; but Im unsure where t put the PayScale[PayScale2[i]]